# Problem with loading file using Laravel and vue

Tags: php, typescript, vue.js, networking

I did try login to my localhost and noticed that when I try to do it, the one doesn`t want to load. It writes that I have an error on it "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Maybe someone know how to fix with problem

I did try to clear php cache, restart commands like yarn hot and php artisan serve

Comment: change port:
php artisan serve --port=8089

Comment: still the same problem